# C# Webclient Time out while visiting few websites

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webclient, connection-timeout

I am able to visit all webpage using webclient in my windows 7 pc however, 
same code is not working on windows server 2008 R2.

Here is one of the sample website : https://www.euronext.com/  working fine using webclient in win7 but not working in 2008 R2 server.

Following is the code snipped used by me :

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["User-Agent"] =
    "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0) " +
    "(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; " +
    ".NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

    // Download data.
    byte[] arr = client.DownloadData("https://www.euronext.com/");

    // Write values.
    Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---");
    Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);
}
```

I tried the following code too:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

// Set user agent and also accept-encoding headers.
client.Headers["User-Agent"] =
    "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)";
client.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";

// Download data.
byte[] arr = client.DownloadData("https://www.euronext.com/");

// Get response header.
string contentEncoding = client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Encoding"];

// Write values.
Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---");
Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);
Console.WriteLine(contentEncoding);
```

can someone guide me if I am mising something here

Thanks for anticipation.

Regards,
Sharez

Exception Details

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) at CapitalIQ.WebCrawler.Lib.CookieAwareWebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) in C:\myProject\MsHtml\Classes\WebClient\CookieAwareWebClient.cs:line 62 at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: Also I tried the following code too.

Comment: Post the exception you're getting, and possibly stack trace. Are you able to browse to that website from the server? Some servers have firewall rules preventing outbound internet traffic.

Comment: Ted NyBerg : Yes I am able to visit the website from the server. Everything looks fine in browser. I have appended my query with the exception